# Not able to answer protected question despite enough reputation

Tags: bug

[image: Why would I not be allowed to answer? My reputation is 101. Is it because the reputation count includes 100 bonus reputation?]

Why would I not be allowed to answer? My reputation is 101. Is it because the reputation count includes 100 bonus reputation?

On the privileges page, I am able to see that I have the rights to answer protected questions.
[image: Privilege page - I am seeing being granted the privilege]

Answer (score 6):

Read this page:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user

It says here:

> Note that one needs to earn 10 rep on the site to be able to answer a protected question. The association bonus does not count.

You need to **earn** 10 rep on the site, and not get it through bonuses. This means that you need to get upvotes or edit posts.

Otherwise, you cannot anwers protected questions.

Comment: Don't we then need to change this page:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/ 
Attached a screenshot of how it looks to me :)

Comment: @NiravZaveri True, why not go raise on [meta.se]?